# IntelliJ IDEA: Python plugin does not highlight Python code

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have some problems whith IntelliJ IDEA Python plugin.

I've got a Java project with a few modules. And I want to add one module for Python tools-scripts which I use to generate some files.

I downloaded  and installed Python plugin (version 2.6.6.) for my IDEA (10.0.2 Ultimate). Then I added Python SDK to the project and created new Python module. Then I added `/src` dir to this new module.

When I right-click on this module, I have a context menu item **New -> Python file**. I can add my `.py` file to my module. Also I can create Python Run/Debug Configuration. And IDEA can launch my script. But IDEA doesn't highlight Python syntax. It marks Python module with Python icon, but my Python file is marked as a text file.

I have inspected all settings, but I failed solving this problem. `/src` is marked as 'Source folder' in 'Project Structure' dialog.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See **Settings | File Types**, verify that .py extension is associated with Python file type.

Comment: Thank you! That was a problem! `*.pyw` extension was associated whith Python script files.